# How to properly get result array in async eachSeries for Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-async

I'm trying to use async `eachSeries` in order to code *what's the report count for every category*. Categories and Reports and stored in separate collections, then I first get available categories and perform a count search on them.

This is my code:

```
    Category.find({},{_id:0, name: 1}, function (err, foundCategories) {
        async.eachSeries(foundCategories,
            function (item,callback) {
                Report.count({category: item.name}, function (err,count) {
                    var name = item.name;
                    console.log(count);
                   return callback(null,{name: count});
                });
            }
        ,function (err, results) {

            if (err)
                response.send(err);
            response.send(JSON.stringify(results));
        });
    });
```

The problem is that I'm receiving nothing, the `console.log` outputs actual numbers there, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API of `eachSeries` does not provide any results to the final callback - only an error in the failure case. In the success case, it's just a pure control flow "eachSeries is done" indicator, but does not provide a mechanism for passing values from the worker function. [mapSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapSeries) does provide the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

Similar as Peter's answer, async.waterfall provides you with waterfall-execution of your functions, while passing a return value to the next async function in the waterfall chain.